# Is there a way to display a video with python?

Tags: python, video

I need help to display a video with python. Have been looking for a solution all day and cant't find any example. I just want to show a .mp4 file in python.

Have no idea what to do

Comment: To answer it simply, Yes. To get a better answer, I suggest you [ask a better question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Google your problems before asking them on SO. https://www.google.com/search?q=display+a+video+with+python

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by *display with python*!

For starters, you can use the `xdg-open` command like this.

```py
import os
os.system("xdg-open %s" % filename)
```

You can also use specific applications like VLC in the same way!

Answer (score 0):

If by 'Display a Video' you mean import a .mp4 file into python then you can say:

```
import os
os.system("xdg-open %s" % filename)
```